# Can I force Azure Tablestorage to return an ETag of constant length?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I recently started working on some testing for Azure TableStorage, and one thing I noticed is that they are apparently doing some weird timestamping for their ETags.

I would like to check something related to the exact byte limitations of data upload, but the problem seems to be that this is hardly reliable as the entity can sporadically get too big or too small as well.

The problem is:

ETags are apparently timestamped, but they are not timestamped *consistently*.

Depending on whether you hit a certain precision in the millisecond range, you might end up with a tag like this:

```
W/\"datetime'2018-11-27T07%3A58%3A29.5163963Z'\"
```

or like this

```
W/\"datetime'2018-11-27T07%3A58%3A29.65348Z'\"
```

Considering the calculation formula for ETag size being:

```
BaseSize (8) + Property name length * 2 ("ETag" -> 8) + 4 + ETag.length *2
```

This can cause differences in the size of the whole entity.

Setting a constant ETag myself before performing a TableOperation is also not possible, as the storage endpoint seems to overwrite it anyways.

Is there any way to force the precision on these values to be constant?

Comment: What have you tried thus far? One of my most immediate thoughts would be to convert to string and then pad it out to x length. But in saying this Ive not worked with their table storage for some time so apologise if this doesnt help

Comment: @SimonPrice The thing is, this tag is set by the server, so everything I change locally does not affect the server. I would like to check that the server returns the statuscode reflecting an overflow. I can calculate it locally and simulate an equal etag, that would somewhat be possible, but it is meh as well.

Comment: not much information in this one but does this help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableentity.etag?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: ETag is not synonymous with timestamp. And you have no control over it. It's there for concurrency purposes, to allow you decide how to handle an update if there's been an update between the time you read an entity and write it back out.